# Is there any advantages of using WCF to Consume REST API?

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-client

Are there any real advantages of using WCF client for consuming REST api. I have api which returns result in SOAP and REST format. Are there any specific advantages of using WCF for consuming this REST API ?

Comment: may be this ans of stackoverflow help you.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502780/wcf-advantages-and-disadvantages][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502780/wcf-advantages-and-disadvantages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current WCF version doesn't have any real client for REST services. You should check `HttpClient` from [Web-API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) as an option (`HttpClient` will be also part of upcoming [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could user the existing WebClient class that is already released in mainstream .Net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx