# Creating a Database Query Service

Tags: c#, web-services, t-sql, windows-services

I've been asked to create **a Service** for our Parent Company. They don't care how I do it, as long as the data is sent to them.

- We have an SQL 2000 Server that receives machine data via [Data Transformation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933484%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (DTS).
- Our Parent Company wants me to create **a Service** that runs every 5 minutes or so to collect new data, summarize it, and forward it to them.
- With my background in Windows Forms development, I naturally think that I should poll the database every 5-minutes using some type of [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then send that data over to our Parent Company.
- The machine housing this data is an old Windows 2000 machine, and our Network Administrator has recommended that I write this as a [Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335693.aspx) on our newer Web Server.
- I created a [Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335693.aspx) a few months back for the Web Server to pull work order information from our Parent Company, but I do not know how to make this Service execute a process every 5-minutes.

Yesterday, I learned how to create an [Insert After Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) when records were added to the table. Unfortunately, the triggers are not called because this old server uses DTS jobs. I was able to learn about [Controlling Trigger Execution When Bulk Importing Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640.aspx), but there does not seem to be a way to modify our old DTS jobs to enable the `BULK INSERT` command. It may not work on SQL Server 2000.

So, with this background, should I create a Windows Service or a Web Service?

How should I proceed?

Comment: Personally, I would go with Windows Service for the simple scalability of it.  Just note, there is a learning curve with WCF. [This thread](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502780/wcf-advantages-and-disadvantages) gives a good synopsis of the pros and cons.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not make a web service for a recurring task.  Web services are not very comparable to a windows service.
btw: A simpler alternative might be to create a command-line app that runs, periodically via a scheduled task (read about the "AT scheduler in Server 2000").  I is just easier to install and make updates because it wouldn't require a reboot of your server each time you make an update.

Comment: So, some basic little .exe file (that doesn't need to worry about having the right version of .NET, etc.) sitting in a folder and set to be called every 5-minutes in Task Scheduler?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Very easy to test and upgrade, etc.

Comment: If you have time, could you look at this error I'm getting? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14287114/153923

Answer (score 1):

If the webservice has a method which you can call that executes the data importing/converting exactly one time, you can use a windows task or cron job to make a request to that method. You can either add this task to the server that is hosting the service, or some other server as long as it can access the webservice.

Comment: Got a link to an example of how to do something like that with a Win Task or Cron Job?