# Console Application - Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application (and I have them all)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Like others, I'm having an issue with a simple console application that reads records from our database.

This small program needs to sit on our file server. It reads new records and forwards a summary off to the parent company.

This is going to be a scheduled task that runs every X minutes.

I do NOT want an Installer, because I don't want the server to require a reboot.

From the screenshot, notice I have almost all versions of the framework already installed and that the debug information is copied into the program folder.

This is the debug version of the program, but no other debug information is being output to the window.

I have tried building at 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0. All versions give me the same error message.

[image: screenshot]

**[UPDATE]:** [wal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224410/wal) asked in a comment for

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup>

<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

This is a console app, so that is literally the entire `app.config` file. I am typically clueless when it comes to these **.config** settings; however, I seem to feel like I have a handle on this one! :)

Comment: Do you know how `VtiUpdate.exe` is determining that .NET is installed?

Comment: In my project's **app.config** file, I have `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>` specified. Is that how to do it?

Comment: Are you targeting the full framework, but only have the client framework installed on the other machine?

Comment: Also, installers do not require reboots all the time.  The only time an installer requires a reboot is if it needs to overwrite a file that is in use.

Comment: The "other machine" is our web server, so I'm guessing it has the full versions installed. Even so, **.NET Framework 2.0** did not have a *client* version, that I know of. Right? So, 2.0 should not have that issue ...I'd think.

Comment: post your app.config ? (or the parts with supportedRuntime and requiredRuntime in their entirety)

Comment: You didn't actually call it app.config did you?  It needs to be foo.exe.config

Comment: I didn't name it. I created a new Console Application, and Visual Studio created the `app.config` file ...and named in "app.config". I do believe I found the answer (posting in a few minutes), but I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally thought someone was going to fuss at me for bad technique when I put my executable here, but I didn't care at the time. I just wanted to get it to work.

Notice where the executable was placed?

[image: screenshot from OP]

It is in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder.

Obviously, the `System32` folder is meant for Windows commands.

**So, why did I place my small executable here?** Because that folder is almost guaranteed to be included in the Windows Environment Path.

I knew someone was eventually going to get irritated with me, so I thought I'd move it today into a suitably named new folder in the `Program Files (x86)` directory.

Well, I did that, and now, like magic, the program runs fine.

So, I'm going to guess that .NET Framework applications are not permitted to run in the `System32` folder.

I would, however, like to hear people tell me what is exactly up with that and why .NET Framework applications can not get in here.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and moving it out of C:\Windows\System32 did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: yes, ok.. BUT WHY can't it run in system32 directory? nobody knows that?!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the .Net installation is corrupted. You can try the following tool to clean .net framework and re-install.

[.net framework cleanup tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/08/04/10336934.aspx)

Comment: Do you think it is corrupted on our server? If I change the `app.config` to point to another framework and I still get the error, does that mean all versions are corrupt? Other .NET apps are up and running.

Comment: I can not find any other explanation; if I were you I would create a simple console application just to test whether the framework is working properly in the server.